# How to send files in a SOAP web service with Spring WS

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am creating my first SOAP Web Service with Spring WS by following this article http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html. So far it seems to make sense and is very well explained. However, I have the need to send an image file along with some data.

for example, I will send: `username = foobar  profileimage = <some file>`

I understand that Spring WS uses contract first approach so I have to make the WSDL first (either generate it or make by hand).

**Question**

But how can I allow for files to be sent as well (as attachments or other means).

Also, I will finally be using the Spring WS grails plugin

Comment: do one way. you can send encoded byte array as profile image. at end you decode the same.